# In Verilog, does an event control always execute once at the beginning?

Tags: verilog

As illustrated in the image below, there is an event control with the variable r (for reset). I have not initalized c in  the top module, but it shows in simulations that it starts at a low state. The only reason I think this is is due to the c output being set to 0 from the always @(r) statement. Why does this execute if r does not change? Or is it technically 'changing' when I initialize it in my simulation?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables of the type 'reg' start simulation with the value of 'x'.

Any assignment after that, also an initial assignment, will be seen as a change and will  trigger the `always @(r)` statement. Thus your `c` can change at time 0.

---

Having said al that: you code is behavioral and can not be synthesized as you have multiple drivers for `c.

Additionally the behavioral code is open to race conditions: if `clk` rises and `r` changes at the same time it is undefined in which order the two statements will be executed.

Besides all that your `c` is reset if `r` **changes**. Thus not only from 0 to 1 or from 1 to 0 but also any x or z change. There is no actual logic which can implement that in reality.

There are standard code templates in Verilog how to make a register with an asynchronous reset:

```
always @(posedge clk or posedge reset)
   if (reset)
      c <= 1'b0;
   else
      c <= ....
```

Last but not least:
***Do not post picture of code. Paste the actual code.*** A prime example is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59509600/why-am-i-getting-syntax-error-near-endmodule/59510824#59510824) one where I would have had one hell of a time spotting the back-quote if the the user had not, correctly, pasted the original code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Time 0 initialization is not well defined in Verilog. Since `r` is defined as a wire, some simulators start all wires in the `z` state. Then if your testbench drives it with an uninitialized variable in the `x` state, there is a `z` to `x` transition at time 0.

Your code is not using a *named event*. That requires declaring a signal with the `event` data type. You are using an *event control*. That means what for the expression after the `@` to change from any value to another. You probably want to combine that with the other always block as in

```
always @(posedge clk or posedge r)
   if (r)
      c <= 1'b0;
   else
      c <= ...
```

BTW, it would really help to post your code as formatted text instead of a picture of the code.